# purpose of symbolic links when mounting via fstab

Tags: mount, symlink, fstab

Considering the following instructions I found online for how to auto-mount a directory at startup:

> 1. Make the symlink:
>
>    ```
>    sudo ln -s `which gdfs` /sbin/mount.gdfs
>    ```
> 2. Add the entry to /etc/fstab:
>
>    ```
>    /var/cache/gdfs.creds /mnt/gdrivefs gdfs allow_other 0 0
>    ```
> 3. Optional: Manually mount
>
>    ```
>    mount /mnt/gdrivefs
>    ```

What is the point of creating the symlink? Is that supposed to be necesary for adding something to fstab?

Why is the symlink called "mount.gdfs"? Why not just "gdfs"?

Is the **mount.** prefix a thing? Does the kernel know when it comes across the "gdfs" in that line in fstab to go looking for something with a "mount." prefix in sbin?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

When you run `mount -t foo ...`, or use an entry in `fstab` with filesystem `foo`, `mount` actually looks for `mount.foo` helper binary. From [`man mount`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/mount.8.html) in Ubuntu, for example:

> For most types all the mount program has to do is issue a simple
>   mount(2)   system   call,  and  no  detailed  knowledge  of  the
>   filesystem type is required.  For a few types however (like nfs, nfs4,
>   cifs,  smbfs,  ncpfs)  ad hoc code is necessary. The nfs, nfs4, cifs,
>   smbfs, and ncpfs filesystems have a  separate  mount program.  In 
>   order  to make it possible to treat all types in a uniform way, mount
>   will execute the program /sbin/mount.TYPE (if that exists) when called
>   with type TYPE.  Since various versions of the smbmount  program  have
>   different  calling  conventions, /sbin/mount.smbfs may have to be a
>   shell script that sets up the desired call.

So, no, the kernel is Jon Snow, but `mount` knows to look for `/sbin/mount.*` commands.